# TYPO3 in custom action ->findAll() don't work

Tags: controller, typo3, action

I want to work with a custom action in my extension.

->findAll() works in the listAction, but not in the customAction.
What could be the reason for this?

Here is the code

```
/**
 * action list
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $issues = $this->issueRepository->findAll();
    
    $this->view->assign('issues', $issues);
}

/**
 * action custom
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function customAction()
{
    

    $issues = $this->issueRepository->findAll();

    $this->view->assign('issues', $issues);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue with...

1. your plugin configuration. Make sure, you have added a storage Id for your plugin and constant settings.
2. You can bypass storage settings from your repository. Goto your repository and add below initialize object function.

```
/**
* initializeObject
*/
public function initializeObject() {
        /** @var $querySettings \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings */
        $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');

        // don't add the pid constraint
        $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
}
```

Probably, this will work for you.

Comment: Great! you can close the question then ;)